# how to find an element in a nested structure and return index

Tags: python, list, random

I have a square grid represented by a list of list of lists - for example:

```
grid = [[[9,3], [], [4]], 
        [[10, 1, 2], [], [11,5]],
        [[8], [7, 6], []]]
```

There is no limit on the lengths of the innermost lists (cells). The grid must contain all integers from 1 to n, where n is a given number (in this case, 11), and each number can only appear once.

I need to select a random number between 1 and n with uniform probability and return the location of the number (i.e. for '3' I would need grid[0][0][1]). Because the probability needs to be uniform, I can't just select a random cell, and then select a random number in the cell, because that would bias the selection towards numbers in cells with fewer numbers in them.

My initial approach has been to generate a random number between 1 and n, and then look through the entire grid for the number. However, the grid can become quite big. What is a more optimal approach to this problem?

Comment: why isn't `random.randint` uniform enough? How does the "grid" affect the uniformity of the selection?

Comment: How is this "grid" being populated and what does it represent? If performance becomes an issue it may be better to use a different data structure

Comment: @DeepSpace we still need to get the location of the randomly generated number

Comment: So your question is really "how to find an element in a nested structure", not "how to randomly select a number", correct? if so, edit the question

Comment: `because that would bias the selection towards numbers in cells with fewer numbers in them.`, how? Just select 2 random numbers(uniformly) for two indexes. Go to the index using `grid[index1][index2]` and you get a list. Now, if the obtained list is not empty, select a number from the list randomly. The whole thing takes constant time(`O(1)`).

Comment: @AjayDabas because the probability of selecting a number if it is the only number in the cell is 1/N where N is the number of cells. The probability of selecting a number if its cell has 3 numbers is (1/N)*(1/3) etc.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks for explaining. `the grid can become quite big`, can you provide an estimate of the size of a large grid? Maybe you can choose a different data structure for performing the task more efficiently.

Comment: @AjayDabas up to 30x30? What data structure might you suggest?

Comment: I suggest using an array of size `N`(assuming N<10^9). Now iterate through the grid once (max 30x30 won't take much time) and for each number `i` you get in the grid, add it's index in the array at `ith` position (`arr[i]=idx`). Now, when you generate a number, you can get its corresponding index in the grid using array in constant time(`O(1)`). So, if you generate a random number `K` times, time complexity of approach remains `O(K+N^2)`(N^2 due to iterating through grid once) instead of `O(K.N^2)`. Alternatively, you can do it using hashmap instead of array.

Comment: Answer by @Cohan explains my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to find a number of items in the grid, you can create a map of the array and then just lookup the random number in the locations dictionary. But if you're only ever going to need to find a single number in a grid, then you can just power through it until you find it.

```
grid = [[[9,3], [], [4]], 
        [[10, 1, 2], [], [11,5]],
        [[8], [7, 6], []]]

locations = {n: (i, j, k)
    for i in range(len(grid))
    for j in range(len(grid[0]))
    for k, n in enumerate(grid[i][j])
}

print(locations)
# {
#   1: (1, 0, 1), 
#   2: (1, 0, 2), 
#   3: (0, 0, 1), 
#   4: (0, 2, 0), 
#   5: (1, 2, 1), 
#   6: (2, 1, 1), 
#   7: (2, 1, 0), 
#   8: (2, 0, 0), 
#   9: (0, 0, 0), 
#   10: (1, 0, 0), 
#   11: (1, 2, 0)
# }

rand_int = random.choice(locations.keys())
print(rand_int, locations[rand_int])
# (10, (1, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dict that will map your array of arrays like this

```py
arrays_map = {9:'1,1,1', 3: '1,1,2'...}
n = len(arrays_map.values())
random_number = arrays_map[radom.randint(0, n)]
```

Comment: I'm unsure how this is faster than just iterating through the whole grid and finding matches. How can arrays_map be created in a fast way?

Comment: arrays_map is calc you doing only once and it also allow you to have random without bias easily

Answer (score 0):

If you have variable depth of nested list of numbers, you can do the following, the code is not perfect, just to demonstrate the idea

```
import random

grid = [[[9,3], [], [4]], 
        [[10, 1, 2], [], [11,5]],
        [[8], [7, 6], []]]


number_index_map = dict()
def create_map(grid, index_string): # you could other useful datastructure like list or tuple for storing the index_string
    for i, val in enumerate(grid):
        if isinstance(grid[i], list):
            next_index_string = "%s,%d"%(index_string, i) if len(index_string) else "%d"%(i)
            create_map(grid[i], next_index_string)
        else:
            key = "%s,%d"%(index_string, i) if len(index_string) else "%d"%(i)
            number_index_map[val] = key

create_map(grid, "")
print(number_index_map)


#test
n = 11
random_number = random.randint(1, n)
print("random number %d " % random_number)
random_number_index = number_index_map[random_number]
print("random number index %s"%random_number_index)

# to get back the number from the index string
temp = grid
list_index = random_number_index.split(",")
print("list index ", list_index)
for i in list_index:
    temp=temp[int(i)]
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question well, I suggest that we can use recursion to search various dimensions and lengths in the list and locate a number and it's position:

```
import random

grid = [[[9,3], [], [4]], 
        [[10, 1, 2], [], [11,5]],
        [[8], [7, 6], []]]

def lookfor(num, grid, pos=[]):

    for i in range(len(grid)):

        if isinstance(grid[i], list):
            pos.append(i)
            pos2 = lookfor(num, grid[i], pos[:])
            if pos2 != pos:
                return pos2
            else:
                pos.pop()

        elif grid[i] == num:
            pos.append(i)
            return pos

    return pos

num = random.randint(1, 11)

print(num, '>', lookfor(num, grid))
```